# If statement using UserID?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot that chats when user enters a voice channels.
I can get how to use @username like below,

```
//CODE1
    bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
      let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
      if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
        bot.channels.get('text channel ID').send('Hello here!'+ newMember);
      }
```

returs like this.

```
Hello here! @toko
```

However, I want to use specific message for each user like "heyyy" to userA, "ciao" to userB so I want my code be like this.

```
//CODE2
      if (newMembers ID = A) {
        bot.channels.get('text channel ID').send('heyyy');
      }else if(newMembers ID = B){
        bot.channels.get('text channel ID').send('ciao');
      }
```

I'm new to programming so I don't know how to write this in correct way and where to put CODE2. Please help...

Comment: this is wrong `newMembers ID = A` becasue it must not have `space` between newMembers and ID

Comment: @don'tangryme newMembers ID = A  is just an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `newMembers ID` you mean '@toko' as in the above code, then this:

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    if (newMember == '@toko') {
      bot.channels.get('text channel ID').send('heyyy');
    }else if(newMember == '@samuel'){
      bot.channels.get('text channel ID').send('ciao');
    }      
  }

})
```

Of course the problem with this approach is knowing every new user's id and writing an `if` statement for each one.

Comment: By ID  I meant 16  numerical digits so added little change and worked perfectly!
Thank you sooo much, Randy!